# Can't seek media in audio element in Chrome brower for audio in stored in Azure Blob

Tags: google-chrome, audio, azure-storage

Able to play audio in chrome using audio element but when trying to seek(change the current playing time) it restarts playing from beginning of audio file.

Tried playing other file from FileStack and local file, it plays perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if HTTP request returns partial content for media, if not below is the investigation.

File stack returns with below headers for audio file

```
accept-ranges:bytes
accept-ranges:bytes
access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type, X-No-Stream
access-control-allow-methods:DELETE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT
access-control-allow-origin:*
access-control-max-age:21600
age:5343
cache-control:public, max-age=2678400
content-disposition:inline; filename="8441b29c7dab61f5f38615330b744b59987846714763447555wav.mp3"
content-length:316538
content-range:bytes 0-316537/316538
content-type:audio/mp3
date:Mon, 25 Sep 2017 10:39:44 GMT
etag:"1c3f5b13012a2edc4a74698dc6caf278"
fastly-debug-digest:c89cb1c9d9747149691a99fe814c53edb54a470c54ea853578098f53d0974baf
last-modified:Mon, 25 Sep 2017 09:10:40 GMT
server:nginx
**status:206**
```

Azure blob returns

```
Content-Length:316538
Response of audio request
Content-MD5:HD9bEwEqLtxKdGmNxsryeA==
Content-Type:audio/mp3
Date:Mon, 25 Sep 2017 10:39:43 GMT
ETag:0x8D503FFF76724A4
Last-Modified:Mon, 25 Sep 2017 10:27:04 GMT
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-lease-status:unlocked
x-ms-request-id:dcc6e80e-001e-0023-1dea-3532f0000000
x-ms-version:2009-09-19 <- This is Azure Storage Service version
status:200 <- Not a partial content
```

Need to make Azure blob storage to return partial content (206).

Referring

1. [Set Blob Service Properties - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-service-properties)
2. [Streaming MP4 video files in Azure Storage containers (Blob
   Storage) - thoughtstuff](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/01/streaming-mp4-video-files-in-azure-storage-containers-blob-storage/)

Blob storage used was of a old version that did not support partial content. Verion used is mentioned in response header of HTTP request to media file "x-ms-version:2009-09-19". Need to make it use latest Azure Storage version.

To set default Azure storage version

```
         // Retrieve storage account from connection-string
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client 
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //Set Azure Storage Service version
        blobClient.GetServiceProperties();
        var properties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();
        Trace.TraceInformation("Storage service version " + properties.DefaultServiceVersion);
        properties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2017-04-17";
        blobClient.SetServiceProperties(properties);
        Trace.TraceInformation("Storage service version " + properties.DefaultServiceVersion);
```

On executing the above code once the default Azure Storage Version will be set to latest as of date and any HTTP request that does not explicitly specify any version to use will use default which in this case supports streaming partial content for media.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue through this suggested answer ?

Comment: How can you do this on php/Laravel ?